# Csv file does not get updated after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, csv, pyinstaller

I am using a csv file in a personal project. This is the code snippet which saves to the csv file:

```
def register_item():
    new_entry = [id,radioType.get(),article_entry.get(),radioStyle.get(),color_entry.get(),material_entry.get(),aesthetic_entry.get(),radioRain.get(),radioWind.get(),radioCold.get()]
    print(new_entry)
    with open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + 'Clothes_database.csv','a',newline='') as csv_file:
        writer_obj = writer(csv_file)
        writer_obj.writerow(new_entry)
        csv_file.close()
```

After using `pyinstaller -F clothes_itemizer.py` the csv file does not get updated anymore.
Here is the .spec file generated alongside it

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['clothes_itemizer.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='clothes_itemizer',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Comment: You dont need to explicitly close csv_file, it will automatically be closed after the exit from with.
There could be an issue with the path of csv file, try comparing this path from running the script and running executable built by pyinstaller

Comment: @dreamca4er The path is the same, the CSV file being in the same directory as the script/.exe file. This being said, how can I check this besides looking at the code I wrote?

Comment: just print/log csv path and compare it between running the script and running exe, just to be sure

Comment: @dreamca4er the paths are indeed the same